# Find the last record based on date

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

In my controller, specifically the *Create* action.. I want one of the textbox's to be auto populated with the value that is in the most recent record based on date.

So for example if on 5/2/2016 the mileage on my car was 26.3.. then when I want to create a record for `5/3/2016`, the TextBox should be `autopopulated` with 26.3.

Here is what I have:

```
public ActionResult Create(int? id)
{
    MaintenanceRecord newMaintenanceRecord = new MaintenanceRecord();

    decimal oldMaintenanceRecord = db.MaintenanceRecords.Single(x => x.AircraftID == id && x.DateEntered == DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)).AirFrame;

    newMaintenanceRecord.DateEntered = DateTime.Today.Date;
    newMaintenanceRecord.AirFrame = oldMaintenanceRecord;


    ViewBag.AID = new SelectList(db.AInfoes, "ID", "RegNum");
    return View(newMaintenanceRecord);
}
```

But when I go to the *Create* page I receive:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

So what do I need to modify to retrieve the most recent `Airframe` in the database based on date?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use like the following:

```
DateTime yesterday=DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
decimal oldMaintenanceRecord = db.MaintenanceRecords
                               .Single(x => x.AircraftID == id && 
                               x.DateEntered == yesterday)
                               .AirFrame;
```

Answer (score 2):

More to the point, why do you assume the most recent is exactly one day old?  "Most recent" is simply the one with the greatest value in that `DateTime` column, isn't it?

So simply order descending by that value and take the first record.  Something like this:

```
decimal oldMaintenanceRecord = db.MaintenanceRecords
    .Where(x => x.AircraftID == id)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateEntered)
    .First().AirFrame;
```